# No friendly mobs spawning in Minecraft: Pocket Edition

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I'm on Minecraft PE 0.72, and since a few weeks ago my world stopped spawning friendly mobs. When I first got the app the spawning was working fine. Currently, hostile mobs still spawn as usual under Normal mode, but I can't get any friendly mobs to spawn. All I have left are lots of chickens, and that is only because I grow chickens from eggs in my farm. Besides chickens, I have one sheep in my world. No new sheep or cows (or naturally-spawning chickens) are being added, and I'm on a bit of a shortage for raw materials. Does anyone have any idea of why this is or how it can be fixed?

Comment: I'm not sure of the rules for pocket edition, but in normal version, there's a limit to the number of friendly mobs in an area at a time. I suspect there's a limit to the number of friendly mobs in the world in PE, and your chickens have filled it.

Answer (score -1):

This could be cause you could have too much chicken, like what Yamikuronue said. If there is such a thing as the Minecraft PE forum, you could ask there.